# Definition of the word "patch"

Tags: terminology, patch

Personally, I use the word "patch" as the software equivalent of a [symptomatic treatment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symptomatic_treatment), which makes a patch a **quick-and-dirty bugfix**. However, I'm not sure this is correct, because I often see it is used in other meanings, for example as a synonym of a program update.

What does the word "patch" mean exactly?

**Update**: I think terminology does matter a lot, because it is a fundamental aspect of documentation and communication, and therefore of software development in general. The problem is that **computer lingo is defined rather loosely**, and I don't know which dictionary provides the **definite reference**. Therefore I thought it was a good idea to ask this here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Patch means patch.  Why do you ask?  What does it matter?  What problem is fixed by splitting this hair?  What problem is solved by arguing over this subtle shade of meaning.  Both definitions are right, so why ask?

Comment: S.Lott, words have meaning and it makes perfect sense to know what the meaning is. "Both definitions are right" is also an answer. And this is exactly "why ask".

Comment: @hacker:  Vague words have vague overlapping meanings.  The question is "What specific issue are you trying to resolve?"  Why does one subtle shading of meaning matter?  Provide some context in which subtle meanings can be analyzed.  An open-ended question like this has no actionable answer.

Comment: S.Lott, not everything is done to resolve issues, what issue are you trying to resolve now when you write it? The issue he works on, on the other hand, is his understanding of the word meaning and its perception by fellow programmers. Questions having more than one answer are still valid.

Comment: @hacker:  Disagree.  Everything resolves issues.  If there's no issue, then the "information" doesn't mean anything.  Here's an example:  42.  That's the data.  Since you don't have a specific question solved by 42, the data isn't really informative.  Without a specific problem to solve, there's an indefinite amount of data that might be relevant or might be just "42".  With a specific issue, then specific information can be provided that will specifically solve the specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patch_%28computing%29):

> A patch is a piece of software
>   designed to fix problems with, or
>   update a computer program or its
>   supporting data. This includes fixing
>   security vulnerabilities and other
>   bugs, and improving the usability or
>   performance. Though meant to fix
>   problems, poorly designed patches can
>   sometimes introduce new problems (see
>   software regressions).

Comment: i'm deeply troubled by the fact that wikipedia is cited, but not the jargon file!

Answer (score 2):

You can find the definitions in the Jargon File: [patch](http://catb.org/jargon/html/P/patch.html). Your personal usage of the term seems to fall under 1, while generally the word "patch" has become a strong synonym for "diff" in recent years.

Apart from that, I'm with S.Lott on this one: what does it matter?

Answer (score 1):

In the open source area, a *patch* is a means of communicating amongst developers. The  *patch* itself is a machine and human readable piece of text describing changes to source code.

The word *patch* itself has no connotation of "quick and dirty", or a "fix" in this context. It just is a change to source code.

Search terms for further research: *diff*, *patch*